# php распаковать бинарную строку без unpack

Tags: php, строки, binary

Дана бинарная строка. В ней каждые 4 символа одно значение типа float в формате big-endian.

```
$binary_data; // здесь бинарные данные
$data_num = 3800; // целое значение - сколько байт данных
$bts_float = 4; // 4 символа на значение
for ($i = 0; $i < $data_num/$bts_float; $i++) {
    $tmpbuffer = '';
    $index=$i*$bts_float;
    $tmpbuffer .= $binary_data[$index+3];
    $tmpbuffer .= $binary_data[$index+2];
    $tmpbuffer .= $binary_data[$index+1];
    $tmpbuffer .= $binary_data[$index];
    array_push($result_array, unpack("f", $tmpbuffer));
}
```

Пока `unpack("G*", $buffer);` хоть как-то терпимо раскрывает, но это только для PHP 7.0+, а для 5.6 только примерным кодом выше.

Ошибка:
    {"1":-77.17456817626953},{"1":-77.43785858154297},{"1":-79.72053527832031}...

Вопрос: Всё-ли впорядке с кодом? Откуда взялась "1"?

в Python она распаковывается так: `struct.unpack('!%df' % block, buffer)`, где block = количество значений / 4, buffer - бинарные данные

Comment: А вы посмотрели что у вас в tmpbuffer ? Судя по сообщению об ошибке он у вас пуст. скорее всего вы что то намудрили с индексами при получении байт из входной строки. А еще посмотрите что такое intval http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php его применение тут вообще не понятно

Comment: Я всё поправил, теперь распаковывается, но как то странно. Откуда "1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как код написан, так он и работает. Предположу, что результат вы смотрите чем-то на подобии `echo json_encode($result_array);`

Так вот, если проверить [документацию](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php), то можно заметить, что функция `unpack` возвращает всегда массив. Есть возможность определить значения ключей массива в строке формата, но если ключи в строке формата не упомянуты - то `unpack` [будет использовать простой счётчик параметров начиная с 1](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.2/ext/standard/pack.c#L891). Соответственно для строки формата из одного параметра результатом `unpack` будет ассоциативный массив с ключом `1` и значением - распакованным значением.

Если вам нужно только одно значение - то его в результат и переносите.